# Find connected-blocks with certain value in a grid

Tags: algorithm, collections

I'm having trouble finding an algorithm for my problem.

I have a grid of 8x8 blocks, each block has a value ranging from 0 to 9. And I want to find collections of connected blocks that match a total value of for example 15. My first approach was to start of at the border, that worked fine. But when starting in the middle of the grid my algorithm gets lost.

Would anyone know a simple algorithm to use or can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your current algorithm look like?

Comment: Did you mean an 8x8 grid of blocks? And are there any restrictions on the shape of the "connected blocks"? That is, do they have to be two adjacent blocks, or could you string together a snake of 15 blocks as long as they're all adjacent and all contain the value `1`? Oh, and are two blocks that share only a corner (as opposed to a side) considered "connected"?

Comment: How fast do you need the algorithm?

Comment: Sounds suitable for [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) methods.  Something like a 2-dimensional variant of the [Maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

Comment: Sorry for not answering quickly. Yes it is an 8x8 grid of blocks. With connected blocks I mean blocks directly adjacent, and not diagonal connected. So a snake should be fine yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no simple algorithm exists for this. As for pointing you in the right direction, an 8x8 grid is really just a special case of a graph, so I'd start with graph traversal algorithms. I find that in cases like this, it sometimes helps to think how you would solve the problem for a smaller grid (say, 3x3 or 4x4) and then see if your algorithm scales up to "full size."

**EDIT :**
My proposed algorithm is a modified depth-first traversal. To use it, you'll have to convert your grid into a graph. The graph should be undirected, since connected blocks are connected equally in both directions.

Each graph node represents a single block, containing the block's value and a `visited` variable. Edge weights represent their edges' resistance to being followed. Set them by summing the values of the nodes they connect. Depending on the sum you're looking for, you may be able to optimize this by removing edges that are guaranteed to fail. For example, if you're looking for 15, you can delete all edges with weight of 16 or greater.

The rest of the algorithm will be performed as many times as there are blocks, with each block serving as the starting block once. Traverse the graph by following the lowest-weighted edge from the current node, unless that takes you to a visited node. Push each visited node onto a stack and set its `visited` variable to `true`. Keep a running sum for every path followed.

- Whenever the desired sum is reached, save the current path as one of your answers. Do not stop traversal, because the current node could be connected to a zero.
- Whenever the total exceeds the desired sum, backtrack by setting `visited` to false and popping the current node off the stack.
- Whenever all edges for a given node have been explored, backtrack.

After every possible path from a given starting node is analyzed, every answer that includes that node has been found. So, remove all edges touching the starting node and choose a new starting node.

I haven't fully analyzed the efficiency/running time of this algorithm yet, but... it's not good. (Consider the number of paths to be searched in a graph containing all zeroes.) That said, it's far better than pure brute force.

Comment: +1 because I think this is a good idea. However, are negative weights permitted?

Comment: @Brian, that should never happen, since values are restricted to numbers between 0 and 9.

Comment: That's why I need to read the problem more carefully. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, looking back on this answer, it's incomplete. It never attempts to add any blocks that don't touch the "current" block. The trivial fix would be to look at every block in the stack on every attempt, but that'll make the running time balloon even more. It might be better to run each path nondeterministically, but I haven't figured out how just yet.

Comment: I tried "depth-first traversal" aswell myself, but there is a slight difference with your idea. I'll give it a go. I guess it is never going to be of very high-performance anyway. But aslong as I keep it an 8x8 grid or slightly bigger it should be ok!

Thanks!